# Add a Label to a wxToolBar

Tags: c++, label, toolbar, wxwidgets

I'm creating a wxToolBar from an .xrc File. I want to add a label, but when I do it doesn't take on the gradient of the toolbar. Is there a way to do this?

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

This is the .xrc markup I'm using if it matters. You can see the `wxStaticText` added at the bottom.

```
<object class="sizeritem">
    <flag>wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL</flag>
    <border>0</border>
    <object class="wxToolBar" name="ID_TOOLBAR">
        <style>wxTB_FLAT|wxTB_HORIZONTAL</style>
        <bitmapsize>32,32</bitmapsize>
        <dontattachtoframe>1</dontattachtoframe>
        <object class="tool" name="ID_TOOL_RUN">
            <bitmap>tool_run.png</bitmap>
            <label>Run</label>
        </object>
        <object class="tool" name="ID_TOOL_PAUSE">
            <bitmap>tool_pause.png</bitmap>
            <label>Puase</label>
        </object>
        <object class="tool" name="ID_TOOL_STOP">
            <bitmap>tool_stop.png</bitmap>
            <label>Stop</label>
        </object>
    </object>
</object>
<object class="sizeritem">
    <flag>wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL</flag>
    <border>0</border>
    <object class="wxToolBar" name="ID_TOOLBAR1">
        <style>wxTB_FLAT|wxTB_HORIZONTAL</style>
        <bitmapsize>32,32</bitmapsize>
        <dontattachtoframe>1</dontattachtoframe>
        <object class="separator">
        </object>
        <object class="wxStaticText" name="wxID_STATIC">
            <label>Autopilot</label>
        </object>                               
    </object>
</object>
```

Comment: what kind of png do you use? Do they have an alpha channel? Background? Did you try that with the toolbar sample?

Comment: @Igor I'll check when I get back in to work, but fundamentally how does that relate? I'm interested in the label, not the .pngs.

Comment: true. But then if the image has an Alpha or is transparent or has a background Windows painting of the toolbar background may differ.

Comment: @Igor The images do have transparency...

Answer (score 1):

Normally this should just work, e.g. see the combobox in the toolbar in the sample with the same name. If it doesn't work for you even in the sample, please open a ticket about this on [wxTrac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/) and provide the details about your platform.